# Application stops immediately after a TCP connection

Tags: android, tcp, android-ndk

I am an Android beginner and I try to connect my ARCHOS 101 G9 to another device via TCP/IP 
Wireless Lan. In the Activity of my project I have a function of a library called connectTCP.
So what I am doing is: `connectTCP("175.145.1.105", 10003);` . 10003 is the port number of the host. There is a connection from the ARCHOS to the host with that ip address because I can ping the host from the ARCHOS. But in the main Activity of my project, when the function is called and probably the conection is established, the whole appliction stops immediately. This means that even the application window is closed. Additionally, the LogCat says "Zygote Process 5377 terminated by signal (11)". But there are no exceptions thrown. The only thing I modified in the AndroidManifest.xml was that I included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` . So what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Furthermore, the LogCat says: "ActivityManager  Process ..... has died".

Comment: BTW, `Zygote Process 5377 terminated by signal (11)` is a bit too low-level for us to determine what the actual problem is with your Activity code :P

Comment: You should just post the entire logcat...

Comment: signal (11) is a segmentation fault.

Comment: You need to examine to logcat and stop anything in your program that is concealing exceptions.  You may have the permission misplaced, or be doing networking on the main thread, or some other mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It could be because your not executing the TCP connection request on a separate `Thread`. Read more about this here:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: Well it might be that I am executing the network in the main thread. Actually I am trying to make an tcp connection in the main activity. I take a look at the link you posted. Perhaps it solves my problem. But anyway I also want to add that I use Android 3.2 .

Comment: Yup. Actually, the "crash" will occur on all devices running Android 3.0 and above. I only made the post about "Android 4.0/ICS" because most people who have the issue are testing on Android 4.0 when they realize the problem. But it will happen on Android 3.2 just the same. I bet that's the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try tommorow. But what about the signal (11) issue? Could this be caused by the problem you mentioned?

Comment: If you are using Java to implement your `Activity`... then no, that has nothing to do with it. It's probably just a consequence of an exception that was thrown and resulted in the process being killed. If you are using the `android-ndk` as your tag suggests, then I'm not sure as I'm not familiar with it. You'd have to post more code. That said, you *definitely* should implement the connection on a separate `Thread` either way... so no matter what you are making a step in the right direction. :)